Halide CUDA sample app gives strange run times
I have some familiarity with Halide and am starting to learn to use CUDA with it. To start with I ran the halide cuda_mat_mul that comes with Halide source code.
I got some reasonable if unimpressive timings:
CPU, autoschedule, Adams2019:    4.2ms
GPU, autoschedule, Anderson2021: 3.0ms
GPU, manual schedule:            1.2ms
CUBLAS:                          0.42ms

Does this seem right? I have an Nvidia RTX 3050 Ti laptop GPU and a core i5-11400h CPU
I then tried to get another sample app: camera_pipe running on the GPU.
It comes with schedules for both CPU and GPU. The CMake file is for CPU only. I modified it to do a CUDA build by setting
FEATURES cuda cuda_capability_50
and giving it CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS and CUDA_LIBRARIES
just like in the cuda_mat_mul app.
I also added
output.copy_to_host();
in process.cpp.
I recorded the following run times:
CUDA (manual):  1270ms

cpu auto_schedule Adams19: 10.5ms
cpu manual:                 9.9ms

So CUDA was way slower than CPU.
This was with a single timing iteration. I then tried doing 100 iterations.
CUDA manual 1st iteration: 1270ms
      next 100 iterations:    5.7ms

I then tried 100 iterations on CPU:
cpu manual: 1st iteration: 10.8ms
       next 100 iterations: 5.8ms
cpu auto_schedule (Adams19) 100 iterations:   7ms

Why is the first GPU iteration so slow? Why are subsequent runs almost the same speed on CPU and GPU?
I verified that it was generating the correct output image. I also tried setting input.set_host_dirty(); but it made no difference.
I tried auto scheduling on GPU using Anderson2021 but got the following error:
C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\camera_pipe17\out\build\x64-Debug\camera_pipe_auto_schedule.runtime.lib(camera_pipe_auto_schedule.runtime.obj) : error LNK2005: .weak._ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal13custom_mallocE.default.halide_internal_aligned_alloc already defined in camera_pipe.runtime.lib(camera_pipe.runtime.obj)

There were several more similar looking errors.
Thanks

Note that the CUDA runtime needs to be initialized. This is pretty slow and done automatically when you use a CUDA function. I personally start my code by doing a device synchronization so to pay this overhead once before any computation since it avoid benchmark biases and avoid a big slowdown in the middle of a critical real-time computation.

AFAIK, the compiled PTX code (generic for all GPUs) needs to be compiled to a low-level SASS code (specific to one GPU) and this process can take a small time. The SASS code is AFAIK cached so you pay this once as long as the PTX is left unchanged.

For the subsequent runs, the best is certainly to profile your code with nsight. Wild guess: It might be data transfer which are often expensive. In term of computation, note that you GPU is capable of 2.6 GFlops (5.2 GFlops on FMAs) and is optimized for 32-bit computations. Your CPU can reach 0.65 GFlops on int32 items and 0.43 GFlops on float32 (0.86 on FMAs) in turbo which is small, but 2.6 GFlops on int8 which is not so bad. If you use int8 computations and does not benefit from FMA, then your GPU is less suited for this tasks (there are better GPUs for that, but also more expensive).

Note the above comment assume you can use the Turbo frequency sustainably which tends not to be the case on laptop. The base frequency is 1.65x lower. The same thing is AFAIK true for GPUs (though the gap is smaller : 1.4x on your GPU).

Thanks a lot Jerome. I'll research how to initialize the CUDA runtime and also look into NSight.

I added a call to cudaDeviceSynchronize(); before the timing run. The first iteration now takes 63ms instead of 1270ms. It is much reduced now but still a lot more than the later iterations' 5.7ms. Perhaps this is the PTX to SASS compile time?  The camera_pipe app seems to use int16 for its computations. I'll do a GFLOPS comparison between the CPU and GPU. It seems to be quite a coincidence that they give timings that are so close: 5.8 and 5.7 ms.

This is possible. If the PTX does not change, then the SASS compilation will not happen. I think this is a bit hard to test though since IDK what Halide does under the hood. Another probable explanation is the your GPU is simply in a sleeping/low-frequency mode. You can easily fix this by running a GPU computation just before or manually setup your GPU so to be always in performance mode (which has a strong impact on power consumption though -- there is no free lunch).

Jerome, did you mean TFLOPS instead of GFLOPS? On int16, I'm getting GPU using CUDA cores only=3.5TFLOPS. GPU using Tensor cores only=8.9TFLOPS. CPU using AVX512=0.86TFOPS. So CUDA cores should be 4x the AVX512 speed. That they turn out to be almost equal could happen I suppose as the above are only  peak numbers. It's disappointing; I was counting on GPUs making the computation I need to do feasible.

Yes indeed sorry I meant TFlops. 3.5 TFlops is beyond the reported performance for non-FMA operation so I guess you have some of them. I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_30_series as a reference for your GPU. Tensor-cores can indeed have a much bigger computational power but I assumed that you did not use them in your computation. The AVX-512 results is a bit low but it might be normal if you are not totally compute-bound. Note AVX-512 is not supported as a dedicated unit on your CPU but as a merge of multiple AVX2 units. I wonder if AVX-512 is optimal on int16 due to 3 units.

You can try to see what is the performance bottleneck on nsight. In some cases you can fix it despite the use of a rather high-level API. It is not rare for the GPU code to be less optimal than the CPU one due to unwanted instructions. Typically, integer FMA on global loads. Sometimes, slower 64-bit ones due to a wrong C type used in the code (possibly due to implicit conversions in C/C++). Besides this you need to check the occupancy is good and there is enough parallelism for your GPU (as well as checking data transfers do not take too much time).

GPUs tends to be more difficult to use efficiently than CPUs IMHO. Besides, your GPU is designed for game and not much for image computing : its int16 performance is not very good (same as int32). For example the (server) L4 GPU can reach >10x the performance of your GPU with a similar power consumption (designed for 16/32-bit computations). It is certainly far more expensive though. By the way, I just found out your CPU seems to support VNNI which is significantly faster for integer FMA (certainly at least x2) than classical instructions.

The camera pipe app is written to exploit the kinds of fixed-point instructions that exist on CPUs, but not GPUs, so GPUs are going to be pretty bad at it compared to most other apps. On my machine it's 1.5ms on my CPU (i9-9960X), and 1.15ms on my GPU (RTX 2060). As others have said, the first iteration is slow because that's when Halide initializes the cuda library and compiles all the shaders.
For cuda_mat_mul, nvidia has spent a lot of engineer hours to write optimized matrix multiplies for every GPU. Halide's is tuned for an RTX 2060. On that GPU my timings are 0.69ms for Halide and 0.51ms for cublas.
Make sure you run with the environment variable HL_CUDA_JIT_MAX_REGISTERS=256 set. Matrix multiply is very sensitive to the number of registers available, to the point where it was worth hurting occupancy to get more. In fact it's so sensitive to register availability, that I think to do better I'd need to write in SASS directly, or at least convince LLVM to not reorder loads so far before the uses of those values to shrink the live ranges a bit.
